# Write a new CSV File from Existing CSV File with many Conditions

Tags: python, csv, namedtuple

I want to write a CSV File which gets Data from and depending from an existing CSV File.

Existing_FILE:

```
Date, Value, Name, sh
2022-01-15, 30,00, Monthly1 - #1500, H
2022-01-18, 130,00, Monthly50, S
2022-01-24, 344,00, Bill # 1110 .. blabla, S
```

New_CSV

```
Date, Name, Name2, Value
2022-01-15, fee, Marcus, +30,00
2022-01-18, rent, Oliver, -130,00
2022-01-24, Bill # 110, , -344,00
```

There is many Rules which applay to the existing Data to create the new File. I just wonder which is the best Approach.

Right now I open the existing CSV and write everything to a named Tuple. I think best idea is to write the new CS to a namedTuple array again? So the Coding is clean and selfdescribing?

Would be nice if someone could light me up with a cool solution.

Thx in advance.

Comment: What have you tried yet? please add some code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might like the native DictWriter module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

It's far easier than using NamedTuple.